# SQL Server Adding Count up

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query and I'm getting the result as intended but they're not adding up

My Query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(h.HotelName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', h.HotelName)) AS 'HotelName',       LEFT(r.RoomNumber, 1) AS Floor, COUNT(*) AS 'Rooms'
FROM HOTEL AS h
JOIN HOTELROOMTYPE AS hr ON h.HotelID = hr.HotelID
JOIN ROOM AS r ON hr.HotelRoomTypeID = r.HotelRoomTypeID
GROUP BY r.RoomNumber, h.HotelName
```

My Results

```
HotelName                      Floor Rooms
------------------------------ ----- -----------
John's                         2     1
John's                         2     1
John's                         3     1
University                     1     1
University                     1     1
University                     2     1
University                     2     1
University                     2     1
Utah                           2     1
Utah                           2     1
Utah                           2     1
```

Intended results

```
HotelName                      Floor Rooms
------------------------------ ----- -----------
John's                         2     2
John's                         3     1
University                     1     2
University                     2     3
Utah                           2     3
```

Basically I want the Rooms for each floor to be added up, any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `floor` in the output, then group by it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(h.HotelName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', h.HotelName)) AS HotelName,
       LEFT(r.RoomNumber, 1) AS Floor, COUNT(*) AS 'Rooms'
FROM HOTEL h JOIN
     HOTELROOMTYPE hr
     ON h.HotelID = hr.HotelID JOIN
     ROOM r
     ON hr.HotelRoomTypeID = r.HotelRoomTypeID
GROUP BY h.HotelName, LEFT(r.RoomNumber, 1);
```

I presume none of your hotels have more than 9 floors.

Comment: Awesome worked! Thank you, and you assumed right hotel only has 3 floors :)